# How to open modal wpf window scoped to a tab item

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I have a use case where we have an application with a tabcontrol  with 2 or more tab items . I want to be able to open a modal Window (using Window.showDialogue()) so the user is blocked to do any thing else within the active tab item from where the modal window was opened . But should be able to click on other tab item and continue to do the work .

Currently Window.showDialogue() completely blocks all user interactions until the window is closed . Is it possible to change the scope of the blocking window to just the initiating tab item ?

As an alternative , I have a overlay design to show the popup content using the Panel.Zindex and then disable the underlying controls container . But I would prefer to do the simple way of window.showdialogue().

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: materialdesigninxaml library offers such a feature called `dialoghost`. but i guess, it is a selfmade special implementation. maybe looking at the source code could help you. https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/wiki/Dialogs

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, here is no way to block only part of a `Window` when calling *`ShowDialog`*. The blocking is done at the `Window` level by the OS. You'll have to manually disable that tab.

Be aware that if you simply put another element on top of the tab to obscure it, the user may still be able to access the controls below by using the `Tab` key. You might need to set `IsEnabled` to `false`, or maybe `IsHitTestVisible`, depending on the how you want the application to behave.